# Passing UIImageView Programmatically at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a UITableViewController and wish to pass an imageView at cellForRowAtIndexPath.

the arrays have been set up:

```
func setupArrays (){

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("stepsSwitch") == true {
        titleArray.append(stepsCell.title())
        iconArray.append(iconFunction1.icon())
    }

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("hrSwitch") == true {
        titleArray.append(heartRateCell.title())
        iconArray.append(iconFunction2.icon())
    }

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("weightSwitch") == true {
        titleArray.append(weightCell.title())
        iconArray.append(iconFunction3.icon())
    }
}
```

and  I call them at cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var myCell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as TableViewCell

    myCell.title.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
    myCell.icon = iconArray[indexPath.row]

    return myCell    }
```

In tableViewCell I have the outlets:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var icon: UIImageView!
```

I create the title and icon imageView in separate files.
Icon imageView:

```
import UIKit

class IconFunction1: UITableViewCell{

    func icon() -> UIImageView {
        var imageName = "HR-white-140px-height.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 282.5, y: 8, width: 25, height: 25)
        self.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.layer.zPosition = 10

        return imageView
    }
```

title:

```
import Foundation

class StepsCell: CellProtocol {

    func title () -> String{

        return "Steps"

    }
```

}

In the Main Storyboard I have added a UIImageView with reference outlet as myCell.

**Problem:** 
The code runs without error, the titles load correct, however the tableView does not load the icon.. it is not visible. Why?

**Question:**  How can I pass an ImageView at cellForRowAtIndexPath ?  What am I doing wrong?

The accepted answer does not directly answer my question, however I accepted it because it solved the problem and explained why my implementation was wrong.

Comment: Why does `IconFunction1` extend `UITableViewCell`? The only thing you can do is to debug the `cellForRow` function and see if there is actually an icon assigned or if it's nil or whatsoever.

Comment: @sebastian-wramba Oh, only because otherwise, if I make it of NSObject, I get an error 'IconFunction' does not have a member named 'addSubview'.  If that is an issue I would really like to know how to fix it.

Comment: where do you call iconfunction1?

Comment: Why you need to programmatically create the UIImageView ? Why can't you customize the cell with custom imageview and label and why can't you just set the image property of that imageView ?

Comment: @paulo sorry, at the top  

class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    
    var iconFunction1 = IconFunction1()

Comment: @midhun-mp If you mean passing just the file name of the icon for example?  like var iconName = "HR-white-140px-height.png" and then  at cellForRowAtIndexPath  myCell.imageName =  imageNameArray[indexPath.row] ?  That is possible, but eventually each imageView needs to be different and it means I would need to pass a great deal of customisation.  This seemed cleaner.  But I am not sure what is optimal.

Comment: "but eventually each imageView needs to be different and it means I would need to pass a great deal of customisation. " What you mean by that ?

Comment: What I am doing here is a test, later the image will be a chart from a charting engine.  each chart is different.  Barchart. line chart, plotchart etc.  However, if I can make this code work I can just swap the func icon for func line chart, func bar chart etc.  The alternative is to have the different functions in TableViewCell.swift and pass variables into the functions like y axis values, dates, y axis range, colors etc.  Like I believe you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are changing image view, but it should be an image

```
func icon() -> UIImage? {
    var imageName = "HR-white-140px-height.png"
    return UIImage(named: imageName)
}

iconArray.append(iconFunction.icon())
myCell.icon.image = iconArray[indexPath.row]
```

P.S. Your implementation looks to complicated...

**UPDATE:**
If you want change appearance of your view you should try do as much as possible in Interface Builder. But if you forced to change appearance programmatically you should subclass views e.g.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var icon: UIImageView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        icon.frame = CGRect(x: 282.5, y: 8, width: 25, height: 25)
        icon.layer.zPosition = 10
        var imageName = "HR-white-140px-height.png"
        icon.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is one way to just pass an image, but I want to pass ImageView, not just image.  With this suggestion I can't set for example CGRect of the icon programatically.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for clarifying this.  This is exactly how I have it now.  I interpret the response to my question that it is the recommended implementation. Off topic, but I would very much appreciate if you could tell me the reason why it is recommended to do as much as possible in the IB, rather than programatically?

Comment: Because of auto layout. In the past there were many programmers who created views programmatically for different reasons, but today it is faster and safer start using IB. You still can't do everything in IB, but in most cases it is good approach. IMHO